# GUI máquina expendedora

Tags: java, poo, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, sublimetext3

## Planteamiento

Estoy realizando una maquina expendedora simple con interfaz gráfica.

Quiero guardar la cantidad despositada y que valide si es mayor que el precio de producto que te dé cambio y si es menor que te diga que falta dinero.

## Problema

Al momento de correrlo, seleccionar un producto, ingresar el dinero y darle en el botón de pagar no da cambio ni lanza ningún mensaje.

## Intentos

Como pueden ver lo que intenté hacer es que después de que el usuario ingresa la cantidad, la variable llamada total almacenara la cantidad que está en donde dice dinero despositado.

Anexo imagen de mi interfaz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuiProyecto1 extends JFrame {


JLabel producto,informacion, cambio;
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,pagar;


public GuiProyecto1 () {
    super("Dispensador de chocolates");
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(850,500);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel pizq = new JPanel();

    JPanel pder= new JPanel();

    JPanel superpanel=new JPanel();

    JLabel producto= new JLabel();

    JLabel j = new JLabel();

    cambio=new JLabel();


    superpanel.setLayout(null);
    superpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    superpanel.setSize(860,510);

    informacion= new JLabel();




    j.setBounds(500,380,140,40);
    // j.setOpaque(true);
    // j.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    j.setText("Dinero depositado:");
    j.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    j.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    j.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    j.setFont(new Font("arial",1,15));


    pizq.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    pizq.setBounds(50,20,400,300);
    // pizq.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    pder.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    pder.setBounds(500,100,300,230);
    pder.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    // pder.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    // caracterisiticas del JLabel informacion
    // informacion.setText("Aqui va el pecio y el nombre del producto");
    informacion.setBounds(500,15,300,80);

    informacion.setOpaque(true);

    informacion.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    informacion.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    informacion.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // caracterisicas del JLabel producto
    // producto.setText("Aqui esta su producto");


    producto.setOpaque(true);

    producto.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    producto.setBounds(50,370,400,50);


    cambio.setBounds(650,380,100,40);
    cambio.setOpaque(true);
    cambio.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //cambio.setText("etiqueta cambio");
    cambio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    cambio.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);






    //añadir botones
    JButton b1= new JButton("a");
    pizq.add(b1);
    b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b2= new JButton("b");
    pizq.add(b2);
    b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b3= new JButton("c");
    pizq.add(b3);
    b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b4= new JButton("d");
    pizq.add(b4);
    b4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b5= new JButton("e");
    pizq.add(b5);
    b5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b6= new JButton("f");
    pizq.add(b6);
    b6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b7= new JButton("g");
    pizq.add(b7);
    b7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b8= new JButton("h");
    pizq.add(b8);
    b8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b9= new JButton("i");
    pizq.add(b9);
    b9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);


    // Crear action listeners
    b1.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b2.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b3.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b4.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b5.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b6.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b7.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b8.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b9.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());

    // Cambiar color de botones
    b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b8.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    // creo imagenes

    ImageIcon ferrero = new ImageIcon("ferrero.jpg");

    ImageIcon hershey = new ImageIcon("hershey.jpg");

    ImageIcon carlosv = new ImageIcon("carlosv.jpg");

    ImageIcon reeces = new ImageIcon("reeces.jpg");

    ImageIcon kitkat = new ImageIcon("kitkat.jpg");

    ImageIcon crunch = new ImageIcon("crunch.jpg");

    ImageIcon larin = new ImageIcon("larin.jpg");

    ImageIcon snicker = new ImageIcon("snicker.jpg");

    ImageIcon baby = new ImageIcon("baby.jpg");



    // añadimos las imagenes a los botones Y redimensiono al tamaño del boton

    b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ferrero.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(hershey.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(carlosv.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(reeces.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(kitkat.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(crunch.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(larin.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(snicker.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(baby.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));



    //añadimos botones al panel derecho
    JButton peso1 =new JButton("1");
    peso1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso1);


    JButton peso2 =new JButton("2");
    peso2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso2);

    JButton peso5 =new JButton("3");
    peso5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso5);

    JButton peso10 =new JButton("4");
    peso10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso10.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso10);

    JButton pagar =new JButton("Pagar");
    pagar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(pagar);

    JButton limpiar =new JButton("Borrar");
    limpiar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(limpiar);


    // crear imagenes para el panel derecho

    ImageIcon moneda1 = new ImageIcon("1peso.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda2 = new ImageIcon("2pesos.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda3 = new ImageIcon("5pesos.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda4 = new ImageIcon("10pesos.jpg");


    // agregar imagenes a los botones

    peso1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda1.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda2.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda3.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso10.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda4.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));





    // action listeners panel derecho

    peso1.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso2.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso5.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso10.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    pagar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    limpiar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());






    superpanel.add(pizq);
    superpanel.add(pder);
    superpanel.add(informacion);
    superpanel.add(producto);
    superpanel.add(j);
    superpanel.add(cambio);
    add(superpanel);
    setVisible(true);
}



    int cantidadA=0;
    int cantidadB=0;
    int cantidadC=0;
    int cantidadD=0;


        public static void main (String [] args){

            GuiProyecto1 ventana =new GuiProyecto1();
        }

        public class BotonPulsadoListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        switch(e.getActionCommand()){
            case "a": informacion.setText(" Chocolate ferrero $8 ");
            break;
            case"b": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Hershey $13 ");
            break;
            case "c": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Carlos V $5 ");
            break;
            case "d": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Reeses $12");
            break;
            case "e": informacion.setText(" Chocolate KitKat $20 ");
            break;
            case "f": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Crunch $9");
            break;
            case "g": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Larin $4 ");
            break;
            case "h": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Snicker $7 ");
            break;
            case "i": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Baby Ruth $10 ");
            break;

        }

    }



}


    public class botonCambio implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            int contador=0;
            String f1="Favor de ingresar las monedas";
            String f2= "Su cambio es: $ ";
            String f3="Deposite mas monedas!";
            String f4= "Recoja su producto";

            // int p1=8;
            // int p2=13;
            // int p3=5;
            // int p4=12;
            // int p5=20;
            // int p6=9;
            // int p7=4;
            // int p8=7;
            // int p9=10;
            int precio;

            int contador1=0;

            int contador2=0;

            int contador3=0;

            int contador4=0;

            int contadortotal=0;
           
            //contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());

            switch(ae.getActionCommand()){



                case "1":   
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                             contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador1=contador+1;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador1);
                            //cambio.setText(""+contador);

                break;

                case "2":
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                             contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador2=contador+2;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador2);

                break;

                case "3":   
                             if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                                contador=0;
                             else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador3=contador+5;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador3);
                break;
                case "4":   
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                                  contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador4=contador+10;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador4);
                break;
            }

                switch(ae.getActionCommand()){

                case "Pagar":int total=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            if (ae.getSource()==b1){
                                precio=8;
                                if (total>precio){
                                    int cambioo=total-precio;
                                    informacion.setText(f2+cambioo);
                                }
                            }
                            if (ae.getSource()==b2){
                                precio=13;
                            }
                            if (ae.getSource()==b3){
                                precio=5;
                            }
                            if (ae.getSource()==b4){
                                precio=12;
                            }
                            if (ae.getSource()==b5){
                                precio=20;
                            }
                             if (ae.getSource()==b6){
                                precio=9;
                            }
                             if (ae.getSource()==b7){
                                precio=4;
                            }
                             if (ae.getSource()==b8){
                                precio=7;
                            }
                             if (ae.getSource()==b9){
                                precio=10;
                            }
                break;
                case "Borrar": cambio.setText("");
                break;
            }   
        }      
    }     
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el fallo esté en la inicialización de las variables dentro del actionPerformed()

```
int contador=0;
int contador1=0;
int contador2=0;
int contador3=0;
int contador4=0;
int contadortotal=0;
```

Creo que esas variables tendrían que declararse fuera de la función actionPerformed() e inicializarse cada vez que se inicie el proceso de hacer una compra.

Si las inicializas dentro, cuando le das para pagar se han vuelto a poner todas a cero.

El código es un poco engorroso y te aconsejo nombrar las variables adecuadamente y simplificar código repetitivo, te ayudará bastante a la legibilidad del mismo, a ti y a otros. Espero que la respuesta te sea satisfactoria.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo, he hecho lo que me ha indicado pero sigue sin realizar la funcion correctamente, por otro lado tienes razón intentare mejorar y simplificar mi código, apenas estoy empezando en la programación por lo que me cuesta eso, aprecio mucho las observaciones!

Comment: Puedes revisar el case "Pagar"; no lo veo muy congruente. Puedes explicar qué tratas de hacer ahí.

Comment: Buenos dias, lo que intento en ese case es recuperar la cantidad del Jlabel donde dice dinero depositado, y guardarla en la variable total, después comprobar si total es mayor que el precio del producto darle el cambio al usuario, despues quiero comprobar si es menor decirle que el monto es insuficiente yo creía que estaba todo bien hasta que lo ejecuté y no hacía lo que debería, voy a anexar a mi pregunta una imagen de mi interfaz para que se aprecie mejor

Comment: Yo veo que la aplicación sólo actúa  en la condicional (ae.getSource()==b1), para el resto de casos b2, b3... sólo cambia el valor de la variable precio.

Comment: Efectivamente solo intenté realizar una acción pero al ver que nisiquiera en la primera hace lo que debería ya las demás no las completé

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que hagas un punto de interrupción en "pagar" e ir instrucción por instrucción y ver si las variables contienen el valor esperado para poder ir dilucidando donde está el fallo. En la teoría hablamos de algo muy simple. Llegados a la instrucción informacion.setText(f2+cambioo); la variable cambioo tiene el valor esperado.